# Switching both GND and POWER

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, control, switching

I have multiple sensors and I need to completely isolate them from each other while working (in terms of Vcc and gnd).

What's the most reliable option to completely switch gnd and Vcc (not only one of them) of a sensor to isolate it from the other ones?

To be more specific, I have an ATmega2560 microcontroller that takes readings from two analog sensors (conductivity and pH.)  All are powered by 5VDC. Each driver consumes less than 100 mA.

To be able to get correct readings from the pH sensor, the conductivity sensor driver must be completely isolated from the circuit (Vcc and gnd.)

I'm asking for a way to safely isolate the conductivity sensor from the circuit when not needed.  The switching rate may be around 100 times per day.

pH driver shematic:
[image: pH schematic]

EC driver schematic:
[image: EC schematic]

[image: Control Block Diagram]

after some research i found that reed relay is the most convenient method in my situation, much longer life time and lower power requirements than electromagnetic relays and i found this in digikey:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/littelfuse-inc/HE3321A0400/133237

Do you know if these kind of relays are suitable in my case in terms of operation life time and complete switching of Vcc and gnd ?

Comment: What voltage levels, current levels, output types? This may influence whether we suggest semiconductor switches or relays. How many? This influences the integration level.

Comment: `I need to completely isolate them from each` Then use mechanical relays. Cut the VCC first, then cut GND. And apply GND first, then apply VCC. PS: What's the main reason for this? What's the reason behind not isolating the data (or read, whatever it is) rails only?

Comment: It depends. If you don't need fast switching, preserved signal integrity during switching etc then use relays. The question is too broad to answer. Also define "reliable"... any particular amount of operations over time?

Comment: Are you able to send a digitized signal and use an opto-isolator so that you can avoid the switching ?

Comment: Post a schematic, please. And don't put "edit" in your post when you edit it -- we can already see the edit history if we want to.

Comment: @RohatKılıç mechanical relays have a short number of cycles (around 100k cycles) which will shorten my device operation time to about 3 years.
what about using reed relays or SSRs ?

Comment: after some research i found that reed relay is the most convenient method in my situation, much longer life time and lower power requirements and i found this in digikey:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/littelfuse-inc/HE3321A0400/133237

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD ??